# Use Anonymous authentication in MVC4 on single controller when the whole application uses Windows Authenticaion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have an MVC4 Web application which uses Windows Authentication, that is in web.config  I have
    `<authentication mode="Windows" />`
 And that works fine and everything is ok.

However now I need a controller (an Web API controller in fact) that should be accessed anonymously from a third party component. The problem is that every time I want to invoke this method it requests user credentials.

I tried putting `AllowAnonymous` attribute to controller and methods but it was not successful.

`[AllowAnonymous]
public bool Get(string Called, string Calling, string CallID, int direction)`

I checked on both IIS Express and IIS 8 with Anonymous authentication and Windows authentication enabled.

It seems that windows authentication precedes any other authentication and cannot be overridden.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your Web.config. Here, my controller is named "WebhookController".

```
<location path="Webhook">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

[See this KB article for more info.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

**Edit**
 - As Erik mentioned below, in MVC applications you should not use web.config `<authorization>` tags for security. Instead, use `[Authorize]` attributes. Doing so will allow your `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes to work correctly. [You can read more about this here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous)

Comment: I don't think this will work for me. This setting is overridden by  '<authentication mode="Windows"  />' and the web site still requires user name and password in order to access. Apart from that I am using MVC and such configuration settings in web.config might not always help because of routing.

Comment: It works for me. I'm also using `<authentication mode="Windows">` with MVC3. I haven't setup any special routing rules though. You may need to mess with the location path.

Comment: Giving it a second try - it works. It seems `AllowAnonymous` attribute is not sufficient with windows authentication and 'location` tag is what works best. Thanks for pointing me what might be the right solution for the problem!

Comment: +1 This fixed a problem I was having. Although we used `<allow users="?"/>`  instead to allow anonymous users.

Comment: The problem with use Web.config location for security is that this has to match all possible URL's that could be used to access a URL.  When you consider default routing, that could mean you have to create a lot of location entries.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer seems to be out of date, so...

In your web.config, remove these lines:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

In the solution explorer, click your project, then click f4 (or open the properties explorer). Enable Anonymous Authentication.

Now you're free to use the `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous` Attributes. They're pretty straightforward, `Authorize` means the user needs to be authorized in order to access the action or controller, `AllowAnonymous` means the opposite. If an unauthorized user attempts to access a controller or action with the `Authorize` attribute, they'll be redirected to a login page. If you put `Authorize` on a controller it applies to all the controller's actions, except ones with `AllowAnonymous`.

Answer (score 1):

`web.config` should not be touched as indicated [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/).

In order to achieve desired result `AllowAnonymous` and `[Authorize]` (and maybe some custom authorization attribute, if needed) should be used.

Steps to be performed:

1. Ensure IIS has both *Anonymous Authentication* and *Windows Authentication* configured for the web application / web site
2. All controllers should use `[Authorize]` attribute. This can be easily achieved if all inherit from a common controller class (e.g. BaseController / BaseApiController). E.g.:

   ```
   [Authorize]
   public class BaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
   {

   }


   [Authorize]
   public class BaseApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
   {

   }
   ```
3. Add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to all actions that are supposed to be anonymous. E.g.:

   ```
   [RoutePrefix("Api/Anonymous")]
   [Authorize]
   public class AnonymousController : ApiController
   {
       [HttpGet]
       [Route("GetServiceStatus")]
       [AllowAnonymous]
       public string GetServiceStatus()
       {
           return "OK";
       }
   }
   ```