# Webhooks on Windows Authenticated Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication, webhooks

I have an MVC3 site that uses Windows Authentication.

I need some way to kick off code on the site through a batch file. My existing solution is to use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to call the methods of one of my controllers (I believe this is called a webhook?) However I'm running into authentication problems, and I don't want to include a domain user/password in the batch file.

I was considering creating a seperate site that uses Anyonymous auth for this one controller, but figured there has to be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding [AllowAnonymous] to the controller method that you are using?  That should get around the need for authentication if that is what you really want to do.  Another option would be to try setting a <location> attribute in the web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can use Kerberos authentication in cURL

```
curl.exe --negotiate -u : [url]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I actually answered a [near identical question to this about 2 months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15486836/1080891). I feel like a moron.